# Format a double in a string and keeping the decimal point

Tags: c#, double, decimal, rounding, string.format

In C#, using the double number 191.5 (example), I want to create a string that:

- has exactly 10 characters
- filled with 0 to the left
- includes the dot character (.)
- include exactly 1 decimal

My code :

```
strOut += SubString(10, string.Format("{0:0000000000}", 191.5));
```

The problem with my code is that :

- it rounds (I don't want that)
- it wipes the decimal

My code output :

```
0000000192
```

The output I need :

```
00000191.5
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: What happens if your `double` is more than 10 characters long?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works just fine, don't need the substring.

```
var results = string.Format("{0:00000000.0}", 191.5));
```

Comment: Indeed, I removed the SubString and did exactly this. Thank you very much for all the quick responses from everyone.

Answer (score 1):

I believe

```
strOut += SubString(10, string.Format("{0:00000000.0}", 191.5));
```

does what you want. However, you don't really need the substring in this case unless you are sometimes expecting some much larger numbers and want to truncate them.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
double num=192.5; 
strOut += SubString(10, string.Format("{0:#}", num));
```